# Classes with a list and printing the list individually

Tags: python, list, class

I am having a problem with printing the list separately and individually in order. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this problem? It would just print out the list and not the actual value which is what I want it to print out.

## Class definition

```
class Radio:
    radioStation = 0
    radioMap = ["STATIC", "97.2", "99.6", "101.7", "105.3", "108.5"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.preset1 = Radio.radioMap[0]
        self.preset2 = Radio.radioMap[0]
        self.preset3 = Radio.radioMap[0]
        ## save "STATIC" plus the 5 stations to a list, starting at the zero position
        ## set each of the 3 presets to STATIC (0 location in the list), as well as
        ##      the currently tuned in variable
        ## call the displayLCD method


    def seekNext(self):
        Radio.radioStation += 1
        for i in range(5):
            print(Radio.radioMap)
            self.displayLCD()
        ## add 1 to the currently tuned in variable
        ## if the currently turned in variable is greater then 5, set the currently tuned in variable to 1
        ## call the displayLCD melthod

    def longPressPreset1(self):
        self.preset1 = Radio.radioMap
        self.displayLCD()
        ## set preset1 variable to currently turned in 
        ## call the displayLCD melthod

    def longPressPreset2(self):
        self.preset2 = Radio.radioMap
        self.displayLCD()
        ## set preset2 variable to currently turned in
        ## call the displayLCD melthod

    def longPressPreset3(self):
        self.preset3 = Radio.radioMap
        self.displayLCD()
        ## set preset3 variable to the currently turned in
        ## call the displayLCD melthod

    def displayLCD(self):
        return print("\nCurrently tuned: ", Radio.radioMap)
        ## print the currently tuned in line using the currently turned in variable as the index into
        ## the station list

    def __str__(self):
        return "\nPreset 1: " + " " + str(self.preset1) + " " + "\nPreset 2: "+ " " + str(self.preset2) + " " + "\nPreset 3: " + " " + str(self.preset3)+ " " +"\nCurrently tuned: " + " " + str(Radio.radioMap)
        ## RETURN the three preset values and the currently turned in station in the
        ## required format AS A STRING
```

## main function of the program

```
def main():
    myRadio = Radio()
    option = displayMenuGetOption()
    while option != "10":
        if option == "1":
            myRadio.displayLCD()
        elif option == "2":
            myRadio.longPressPreset1()
        elif option == "3":
            myRadio.longPressPreset2()
        elif option == "4":
            myRadio.longPressPreset3()
        elif option == "5":
            myRadio.seekNext()
        elif option == "6":
            myRadio.shortPressPreset1()
        elif option == "7":
            myRadio.shortPressPreset2()
        elif option == "8":
            myRadio.shortPressPreset3()
        elif option == "9":
            print(myRadio)
        option = displayMenuGetOption()

    def displayMenuGetOption():
    print("\n1 = Display tuned in station")
    print("2 = Program preset station 1")
    print("3 = Program preset station 2")
    print("4 = Program preset station 3")
    print("5 = Seek next station")
    print("6 = Tune preset station 1")
    print("7 = Tune preset station 2")
    print("8 = Tune preset station 3")
    print("9 = Dump Programming")
    print("10 = Turn off radio")
    return input("\nEnter option: ")

    main()
    input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")
```

## This is what it prints out

```
['STATIC', '97.2', '99.6', '101.7', '105.3', '108.5']

Currently tuned:  ['STATIC', '97.2', '99.6', '101.7', '105.3', '108.5']
['STATIC', '97.2', '99.6', '101.7', '105.3', '108.5']

Currently tuned:  ['STATIC', '97.2', '99.6', '101.7', '105.3', '108.5']
['STATIC', '97.2', '99.6', '101.7', '105.3', '108.5']

Currently tuned:  ['STATIC', '97.2', '99.6', '101.7', '105.3', '108.5']
['STATIC', '97.2', '99.6', '101.7', '105.3', '108.5']

Currently tuned:  ['STATIC', '97.2', '99.6', '101.7', '105.3', '108.5']
['STATIC', '97.2', '99.6', '101.7', '105.3', '108.5']

Currently tuned:  ['STATIC', '97.2', '99.6', '101.7', '105.3', '108.5']
```

## This is what I want it to look like

```
enter option: 1

Currently tuned: STATIC

enter option: 5

Currently tuned: STATIC

enter option: 5

Currently Tuned: 97.2

enter option: 2

Currently Tuned: 97.2

enter option: 5

Currently tuned: 99.6

enter option: 4

Currently tuned: 99.6

enter option: 6

Preset 1: 97.2
Preset 2: STATIC
Preset 3: 99.6
Currently tuned: 99.6
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the radio number as the index when accessing the list if you only want to display the current station. Also your class should be refering to self instead of the class name.

```
def displayLCD(self):
    return print("\nCurrently tuned: ", self.radioMap[self.radioStation])
    ## print the currently tuned in line using the currently turned in variable as the index into
    ## the station list
```